# Where is Wacom Settings on Kubuntu 16.04?

Tags: kubuntu, tablet, wacom

Two years ago I tried to upgrade from Kubuntu 14.04 to 15.
But my Wacom tablet (an Intuos 5 Pro touch) couldn't be calibrated, neither map buttons, neither turn on/off touch, neither map to screen.
I stayed with Kubuntu 14.04 until yesterday when I wanted to give a shot on 16.04. But again, it's not like 14.04.
Where is the tablet settings that used to be inside system settings>input?
My tablet is now recognized like a joystick and that sucks.
We tried to install kde-config-tablet in vain. No config screen.
Could the developers please give a solution for this? I need that configuration screen, so full of options, specially mapping for screens and buttons.
Pen pressure and sensibility works, but i can't assign any other functions  to the tablet.
And I see lots of people are with the same problem.
Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to switch buttons 2 and 3 (linux defaults have always been an issue) by running this:

```
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos3 6x8 Pen stylus" "Button" "2" "+3"
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos3 6x8 Pen stylus" "Button" "3" "+2"
```

(however on my last bootup they've ceased working again... sigh)